# IF ELSE IF ELSE IF.... Code wants to get smarter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried a lot to get this code smarter... as you see... it's always the same... one variable can have 6 different values... which decides in which column some other value will be written... if the recordset still exists I make an "update..." else I make an "insert into..."

I tried to do some dynamic sql... but it doesn't work...

I tried to do some "CASE..." code... but it doesn't work...

This code works:

```
-- How many roads must a man walk down...
IF @DatenFeld = 'weaNr'
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @StaDa_Table WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz)
        INSERT INTO @StaDa_Table (DatenSatz, weaNr ) VALUES (@DatenSatz, Convert(nvarchar(20),@DatenWert))
    ELSE
        UPDATE @StaDa_Table SET weaNr = Convert(nvarchar(20),@DatenWert) WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz
ELSE
    IF @DatenFeld = 'weaTyp'
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @StaDa_Table WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz)
            INSERT INTO @StaDa_Table (DatenSatz, weaTyp ) VALUES (@DatenSatz, Convert(nvarchar(20),@DatenWert))
        ELSE
            UPDATE @StaDa_Table SET weaTyp = Convert(nvarchar(20),@DatenWert) WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz
    ELSE    
        IF @DatenFeld = 'nennP_W'
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @StaDa_Table WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz)
                INSERT INTO @StaDa_Table (DatenSatz, nennP_W ) VALUES (@DatenSatz, Convert(int,@DatenWert))
            ELSE
                UPDATE @StaDa_Table SET nennP_W = Convert(int,@DatenWert) WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz
        ELSE
            IF @DatenFeld = 'refErt_Wh'
                IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @StaDa_Table WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz)
                    INSERT INTO @StaDa_Table (DatenSatz, refErt_Wh ) VALUES (@DatenSatz, Convert(bigint,@DatenWert))
                ELSE
                    UPDATE @StaDa_Table SET refErt_Wh = Convert(bigint,@DatenWert) WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz
            ELSE
                IF @DatenFeld = 'inbetrieb'
                    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @StaDa_Table WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz)
                        INSERT INTO @StaDa_Table (DatenSatz, inbetrieb ) VALUES (@DatenSatz, Convert(datetime,@DatenWert))
                    ELSE
                        UPDATE @StaDa_Table SET inbetrieb = Convert(datetime,@DatenWert) WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz
                ELSE
                    IF @DatenFeld = 'uw'
                        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @StaDa_Table WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz)
                            INSERT INTO @StaDa_Table (DatenSatz, uw ) VALUES (@DatenSatz, Convert(nvarchar(50),@DatenWert))
                        ELSE
                            UPDATE @StaDa_Table SET uw = Convert(nvarchar(50),@DatenWert) WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz
```

... so maybe someone which ist more familiar with tsql can help me to get this code smarter?

Comment: *it doesn't work* isn't a very useful comment - please **explain** why and how it doesn't work; do you get an error - if so: ***what*** error are you getting? Is it not returning any values? The wrong values? What did it return and what did you expect??

Comment: You know there is a `case` statement as you've tried it - did you google on it to see how it's used?

Comment: One should not forget to ask the eternal question: What have you tried? so far? "please do it for me lol" does not really work on SO. ;-)

Comment: I think that this belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if it works, and you want to know how to do it better.

Comment: If it works, leave it alone and do the next thing on your list!

Comment: What does "smarter" mean? If the code gives the correct results, is clear to read, easy to maintain and performs acceptably then there's no point in working on subjective improvements such as making it "smarter", "nicer", "cleaner" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this helps:

```
declare @weaNr nvarchar(20) = null
declare @weaTyp nvarchar(20) = null
declare @nennP_W int = null
declare @refErt_Wh bigint = null
declare @inbetrieb datetime = null
declare @uw nvarchar(50) = null

select  @weaNr = case when @DatenFeld = 'weaNr' then Convert(nvarchar(20),@DatenWert) end
        ,@weaTyp = case when @DatenFeld = 'weaTyp' then Convert(nvarchar(20),@DatenWert) end
        ,@nennP_W = case when @DatenFeld = 'nennP_W' then Convert(int,@DatenWert) end
        ,@refErt_Wh = case when @DatenFeld = 'refErt_Wh' then Convert(bigint,@DatenWert) end
        ,@inbetrieb = case when @DatenFeld = 'inbetrieb' then Convert(datetime,@DatenWert) end
        ,@uw = case when @DatenFeld = 'uw' then Convert(nvarchar(50),@DatenWert) end

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @StaDa_Table WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz)
    INSERT INTO @StaDa_Table (DatenSatz, weaNr, weaTyp, nennP_W, refErt_Wh, inbetrieb, uw ) 
    VALUES (@DatenSatz, @weaNr, @weaTyp, @nennP_W, @refErt_Wh, @inbetrieb, @uw)
ELSE
    UPDATE  @StaDa_Table
    SET     weaNr = ISNULL(@weaNr, weaNr)
            ,weaTyp = ISNULL(@weaTyp, weaTyp)
            ,nennP_W = ISNULL(@nennP_W, nennP_W)
            ,refErt_Wh = ISNULL(@refErt_Wh, refErt_Wh)
            ,inbetrieb = ISNULL(@inbetrieb, inbetrieb)
            ,uw = ISNULL(@uw, uw)
    WHERE DatenSatz=@DatenSatz
```

Assuming that all columns are nullable.